# The right preposition in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

> They all share the ethical intention ------ safe transference.

What preposition is the most idiomatic to put in the blank? "to", "of", "for", etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by safe transference? And which preposition do you think matters here?

Comment: @Lambie "safe transference of charity money for example". I first used "to", but then doubted.

Comment: Money=a safe transfer, not transference. Transference is psychology or some other field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preposition that is appropriate here is ***of***.

> They all share the ethical intention ***of*** ...

This is [some thing] in relation to [some other thing] (a noun) and could be written as, "They all share the ethical intention in relation to [something]."

If the [something] was an action (i.e. verb), then the preposition *could be* "***to***". For example, "They all share the ethical intention ***to*** transfer the money safely.", or (more idiomatically) "They all *have* the ethical intention *to transfer* the money safely."

Comment: What about "transferring"? "they share the ethical intention of/to transferring the money safely"?

Comment: With the gerund *-ing* the preposition is also *of*.